# Strip out portion of a url using jquery

Tags: jquery, url, strip

Google produces image thumbs like so
http://images.google.com/images?q=tbn:9vPPg9Y5ojFMeM::www.maniacworld.com/amazing-cars.jpg

I only need the main image url which in this case is www.maniacworld.com/amazing-cars.jpg
I noticed we have :: before the main image url

What is the easiest way to do this via jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery something like this should work:

```
  var result = [yourstring].split("::")[1];
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jkXBH/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery, you can probably just use a regular expression.

```
var re= /.+::/
var newurl = googleurl.replace(re,'');
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rsefq/

Comment: @alex just declaring a variable in javascript. My habit and not necessary in this context.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'http://images.google.com/images?q=tbn:9vPPg9Y5ojFMeM::www.maniacworld.com/amazing-cars.jpg';
alert(str.split('::')[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with JavaScript's `split()` method if you're sure "::" will always proceed what you're after.

```
var parts = url.split("::");
var image_url = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need jquery you can simply use string split with javascript, but if you want jquery here you go:

```
$('urlSelector').attr('href').split('::')[1]
```